# What are the properties of a Unique Associative Hashmap Container vs Associative Hashmap Container

Tags: c++, hashmap

**NOTE:** Sometimes the answers are "as a user you should not worry about implementation details" I will note here that this is a question based on what I want to learn as if I want to implement it.

According to [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueAssociativeContainer.html):

> A Unique Associative Container is an Associative Container with the
>   property that each key in the container is unique: no two elements in
>   a Unique Associative Container have the same key.

That much I understand. What isn't explained further is how the data is stored in the case when the keys are unique and when they are not (I am guessing the reason this is not explained is that it is implementation dependant). So, when the keys are unique, are all buckets 1 element in size? I am thinking not because of collisions, and if so, once the bucket number is determined by the `hasher`, and if the key is unique, how is the element stored in the bucket itself?

What about when the keys are not unique? How are the elements stored and then returned to/from the buckets?

I would appreciate elaboration on other points as well if they relate to how (in general) an *Unique Associative Container* and an *Associative Container* store their elements and differences between them (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

The keys *are* unique in a Unique Associative Container. As described on the page you linked, if you insert some element e with key k, subsequent calls to insert() with the same key k will not insert new elements. Also note from the page you linked that the count() method, which returns the number of elements in a UAC with a given key, always returns 0 or 1.

Your question about "buckets" is unclear. How the container buckets data on the back end -- whether or not a hash map, for instance, handles collisions by chaining or via another mechanism -- shouldn't affect you as a user.

Comment: I am asking as an implementer. I want to learn about this rather than just dismiss implementation details.

Comment: The Unique Associative Container specification itself doesn't specify a bucketing scheme, so you're free to handle collisions as you see fit so long as you abide by the details of the specification I listed above (handling the cases where keys are actually equal rather than just bucketed together.)

Comment: @Samaursa: I would imagine each bucket generally holds several keys that are different than each other.